# Android pegar dados da ImageButton para enviar em um post

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma View do tipo Fragment com um formulário, neste formulário tenho uma imagebutton no qual carrego imagens da galeria do Android quando vou salvar este formulário preciso pegar esta imagem e postar na Base64.

```
public class EditarPerfilActivity extends Fragment {

ImageButton imgButton;

public static EditarPerfilActivity newInstance() {
    EditarPerfilActivity fragment = new EditarPerfilActivity();
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_editar_perfil, container, false);

    btnSalvarPerfil = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btSalvarPerfil);


    imgButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imgperfil);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery(10);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Image Button!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    //AQUI QUE DEVERIA CONSEGUIR PEGAR OS DADOS DA IMAGEM
    btnSalvarPerfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkinfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkinfo != null && networkinfo.isConnected()) {


                nome = hintNome.getText().toString();
                idade = hintIdade.getText().toString();

                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedPath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
                byte[] pathImage = bao.toByteArray();


                if (nome.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Preencha o nome ou Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    parametros = "id=" + IdUser +"&nome=" + nome + "&idade=" + idade;

                    new EditarPerfilActivity.SolicitaDados().execute(url);
                }
            } else {
                //error connecting
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Nenhuma conexão encontrada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(data.getData() != null){
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        }else{
            Log.d("selectedPath1 : ","Came here its null !");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "failed to get Image!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            imgButton.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            Log.d("selectedPath1 : " ,selectedPath);
        }
        if (requestCode == 10)
        {
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            imgButton.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            Log.d("selectedPath1 : " ,selectedPath);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}

public void openGallery(int req_code){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), req_code);
}
```

}

Alguém tem uma idéia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Carreguei a imagem da galeria, a _ImageButton_ quando recebe um click abre a galeria para a escolha de uma imagem, e esta imagem é carregada no mesmo Button, mas quando vou salvar este formulário não estou conseguindo acessar a imagem.

Comment: Mas o que acontece?Consegue debubar par ver se entra em **Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");** depois que seleciona a imagem? Dentro do **onActivityResult**

Comment: Sim a imagem carrega normalmente é quando vou salvar os dados do form que ele não carrega a imagem, parece que não consegue achar a imagembutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seu problema está no `onActivityResult`!

Quando o método `onActivityResult` retorna, ele já entrega uma `URi`
 onde  podemos setar diretamente no `ImageButton`:

```
   photo.setImageURI(data.getData());
```

Também, podemos transformar esta `URi` em um `Bitmap` da seguinte forma:

```
try {
        bitmapPhoto = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
    }catch (final IOException e){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Assim, quando for enviar esta informação, pode se validar diretamente o `Bitmap`!

Segue um exemplo completo:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    /**
     * Código para saber quando retornar em onActivityResult
     */
    final int REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE = 123;

    private ImageButton photo;
    /*
       Instancia da imagem selecionada.
       Se for nula, o usuario não selecionou!
     */
    private Bitmap bitmapPhoto = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        photo = ImageButton.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.photo));
        photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
    }


    public void enviar(final View view) {
        if (bitmapPhoto == null) {
            /**
             * A imagem não foi selecionada!
             */
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selecione a sua imagem de perfil!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            /**
             * Vamos Transformar a imagem em  Base64...
             */
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
            fima byte[] img_byte = stream.toByteArray();
            String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(img_byte, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.i("BASE64", img_str);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Sempre que solicitar uma imagem, sempre vamos passar a constante REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE
     */
    public void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione uma imagem de perfil"), REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // OK, o resultado é positivo
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
           // é a nossa solicitação de imagem...
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE) { 

                final Uri pathImgSelecionada = data.getData();
                if (null == pathImgSelecionada) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URi Nula!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                /**
                 * Passamos diretamente a URi para o Image Button..
                 */
                photo.setImageURI(pathImgSelecionada);


                /**
                 * Transformamos a URi em um Bitmap
                 */
                try {
                    bitmapPhoto = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), pathImgSelecionada);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Valeu thiago realmente deu certo assim, no _onActivityResult_ peguei o Bitmap e consegui trabalhar com ele dentro do _onClick_ Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.